# MYSQL Update query, replace part string containing URL

Tags: mysql

Thanks for taking the time to review my code. I have hundreds of rows to update where I need to remove the URL and the reference for the link. I have tried the below code along with escaping the double quotes, however it continues to throw an error with no help.

Appreciate any help offered.

`` UPDATE `wpsr_posts` SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'<a href="https://www.website.com/category/page.html" >link description</a>',' ')  WHERE post_content LIKE '%<a href="https://www.website.com/category/page.html" >link description</a>%' ``

Comment: perhaps you can start by telling us what are the error messages?

Comment: also, is this [tag:wordpress]?

Comment: Yes it is Wordpress the error message in MySQL is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPLACE(post_content,'<a href="https://www.website.com/category/page.html' at line 2.

Comment: its just my random suggestion, is replacing without the html tag isn't possible? what i'm suggesting here is to reduce the surface of "things that can fail" in that query.

Comment: The issue appears to be escaping the double quotes and the backslashes so that the query runs. If I run a where Like clause with the text it works fine, when I run the query as a REPLACE it doesn't like the special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies as it appears that the question I asked actually didn't contain the issue that I identified in the end. I do hope this will help someone in the future.

```
UPDATE `wpsr_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'<a href="https://www.website.com./category/product/page.html">product &amp; other info</a>', " ") where post_content LIKE '%https%' AND post_type='product'
```

The cause was that the replacement string contained an `&amp;` the semicolon at the end was causing MySQL to end the query at that point.

The solution was to change the mysql delimiter which is defaulted to ; to something that wouldn't appear in the string e.g. ~.

Appreciate your guidance Bagus Tesa.